# React map function gives back same image when mapping random generated image url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

I'm mapping a simple array of team member data. The image url in the data is a random generated cat picture. My problem is that when I map over the array of teammembers, the image of all members is the same. Every time I refresh they all change to another image, but not a different one for each member.

The rest of the data works fine. How can I resolve this?

Example of the data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Jessika",
    "role": "Interaction Design",
    "location": "berlin",
    "image": "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
    "tags": [
      "salmon",
      "red"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Kyra",
    "role": "Project Manager",
    "location": "amsterdam",
    "image": "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
    "tags": [
      "white",
      "gold"
    ]
  },
```

My code:

```
        <div className="grid-item">
          {response && (
            <div className="card">
              {response.map((member: any) => {
                return (
                  <div key={member.name} className="card__container">
                    <div className="card-image">
                      <img src={member.image} alt="Team member" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-content">
                      <p>{member.name}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
```

I tried mapping my response and displaying the data in my jsx. It works fine but the image won't give a unique image for each team member.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const response = [
        {
            name: "Jessika",
            role: "Interaction Design",
            location: "berlin",
            image: "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
            tags: ["salmon", "red"],
        },
        {
            name: "Kyra",
            role: "Project Manager",
            location: "amsterdam",
            image: "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
            tags: ["white", "gold"],
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="grid-item">
            {response && (
                <div className="card">
                    {response.map((member/*: any*/) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={member.name} className="card__container">
                                <div className="card-image">
                                    <img src={member.image} alt="Team member" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-content">
                                    <p>{member.name}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use actual images if you want well-defined results and not a random image generator.

Comment: @Spikatrix I understand, but this is the endpoint I was given for the assignment.

Comment: Does the assignment say all images must be unique?

Comment: @Spikatrix No, but I didn't like the look of it and there had to be a solution :)

Comment: That would be over-engineering. Personally, I wouldn't do it. I believe they would be looking at the overall thing rather than checking if the images are unique.

Comment: @MeesGoudbeek - If this is for an assignment and they've given you that URL, you might use different URLs from the same server and include a note in the code saying why (rather than doing what's in my answer, which does add unnecessary complication to the code **if** you don't actually need the URLs to be the same). Like `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/dog`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/giraffe`...

Comment: @MeesGoudbeek - Or even just hardcoded `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat?1`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat?2`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat?3` etc., again with a note saying why.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback! Will look at it again and see what is the best approach. I'll definitely add a note explaining the choices I've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the URLs are the same, the browser may re-use the previous response when two requests are made at almost exactly the same time. To prevent that, add a query string to make them unique so the browser doesn't reuse the response:

```
<img src={member.image + "?" + member.name} alt="Team member" />
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const response = [
        {
            name: "Jessika",
            role: "Interaction Design",
            location: "berlin",
            image: "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
            tags: ["salmon", "red"],
        },
        {
            name: "Kyra",
            role: "Project Manager",
            location: "amsterdam",
            image: "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
            tags: ["white", "gold"],
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="grid-item">
            {response && (
                <div className="card">
                    {response.map((member/*: any*/) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={member.name} className="card__container">
                                <div className="card-image">
                                    <img src={member.image + "?" + member.name} alt="Team member" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-content">
                                    <p>{member.name}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I've used the member name there, but it may not be appropriate to send that information to the image server. It just needs to be something that's unique to that member and, ideally, doesn't change over time (so ideally, not a random number, though if the image is always meant to be re-fetched, that would be okay).

Or perhaps the member index (since this isn't a React key):

```
{response.map((member/*: any*/, index/*: number*/) => {
    return (
        <div key={member.name} className="card__container">
            <div className="card-image">
                <img src={member.image + "?" + index} alt="Team member" />
            </div>
            <div className="card-content">
                <p>{member.name}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
})}
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const response = [
        {
            name: "Jessika",
            role: "Interaction Design",
            location: "berlin",
            image: "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
            tags: ["salmon", "red"],
        },
        {
            name: "Kyra",
            role: "Project Manager",
            location: "amsterdam",
            image: "https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat",
            tags: ["white", "gold"],
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="grid-item">
            {response && (
                <div className="card">
                    {response.map((member/*: any*/, index/*: number*/) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={member.name} className="card__container">
                                <div className="card-image">
                                    <img src={member.image + "?" + index} alt="Team member" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-content">
                                    <p>{member.name}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

If the image URL may *already* have a query string, you'll want `&` instead of `?`. You could do:

```js
function appendUrlPart(url, part) {
    const delim = url.includes("?") ? "&" : "?";
    return url + delim + encodeURIComponent(part);
}
```

...then `src={appendUrlPart(member.image, index)}`.

---

In a comment you've said this is for an assignment and the URL is given as part of the assignment. Unless the assignment is intended to get you to solve this very problem (that is, if you think the instructor just threw out a URL without considering this possible issue), you might just use other URLs from that server in the "response" data, rather than adding the code above. The code above solves the problem, but if it's not a real problem, you don't want unnecessary code in your solution. Perhaps just use `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/dog`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/giraffe`, etc.; or even just `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat?1`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat?2`, `https://loremflickr.com/640/480/cat?3` etc. Along with a comment explaining why you did that.